# doesnt work when i try to run virtual machines

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I tried to run the machine this poped up

[image]

This text :

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine.

Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes

To run Oracle VM VirtualBox on 64-bit host, you need to enable:

- Virtualization Technology (VTx) and
- Virtualization Technology Directed I/O (VTd).

Boot the computer and enter the BIOS using the designated key (F10?).
Find the above two entries and enable them.

Comment: I found it, can it be named Intel virtual technology?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes

Most machines today are 64-bit.

Restart the host computer and go into BIOS (UEFI).

Enable Hardware Virtualization and VT-x .

Restart the host and try running the Virtual Machine again.

It is always possible your computer does not support hardware virtualization (not all computers do) so you need to check the CPU settings of your BIOS.